# Почему проект не видит bootstrap установленный локально?

Tags: html, css, node.js, bootstrap, npm

У меня установлен bootstrap через npm. При подключении файла bootstrap.css по пути:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

В `index.html`, bootstrap не работает, его классы просто не применяются. При этом в инструментах разработчика видно что файл `bootstrap.css` подключён и можно увидеть исходный файл в браузере. Путь прописан правильно, сто раз проверял. Версия bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2. Пробовал сделать то же самое на другом компьютере, и там всё точно так же, файл `bootstrap.css` подключён но его классы никак не применяются к элементам. Почему-то проект полностью игнорирует их.

Может быть нужно подключить ещё какие то файлы из bootstrap кроме `bootstrap.css`? Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Comment: в консоли пишет что-нибудь?

Comment: Пока не работал в консоли, только устанавливал в ней bootstrap через npm.

Comment: в консоли **браузера** какие-нибудь ошибки есть? когда свой index.html открываете

Comment: В консоли браузера никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: Сложно сказать, очень мало информации, чтобы проанализировать почему не работает.

Comment: Обнаружил интересную закономерность. Ранее я создавал файл index.html командой в консоли через echo "" > index.html, и попробовав создать index.html через обычное создание текстового файла и переименовав его в index.html как ни странно решило проблему, и bootstrap заработал. Теперь не ясно почему созданнный index.html через консоль windows powershell не работает с bootstrap, учитывая что он ничем не отличается от созданного через правый клик-создать-текстовый документ.